# The order of sub-tabs in user's page is strange

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The orders of the tabs that appear under `Activity` section in user's page is:

```
summary
answers
questions
tags
badges
favorites
bounties
reputation
all actions
responses
votes
```

but these consist of (at least the following) different categories:

User's action:

```
answers
questions
all actions
votes
bounties
```

User's reputation:

```
tags
badges
reputation
```

Others:

```
summary
favorites
responses
```

And because the order is mixed up, I find it difficult to find a certain tab. I request that either

1. the tabs are grouped (for example, as I suggested above)
2. the tabs are reordered so that tabs belonging to the same group appear consecutively, and a general, cover term comes first in each group (if any) like the following:

   ```
   summary
   all actions
   answers
   questions
   votes
   bounties
   reputation
   tags
   badges
   favorites
   responses
   ```